# Ordering of except statements in Python

Tags: python

If I have an inheritance hierarchy of exception classes, and in a `try` block if I want to attempt to handle a more specific (derived) exception before a more general one, do I just put the `except` statement for the derived class above the one for the base class?

Is this how I would do it?

```py
class MyException(BaseException):
    pass

class AnotherException(MyException):
    pass

try:
    raise AnotherException()
except AnotherException:
    print('Caught YetAnotherException!')
except MyException:
    print('Caught MyException!')

print('Done.')
```

I have tried it out, and it works, but I'm surprised I am unable to find any documentation about this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check out the documentation of the [`try` statement](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-try-statement) in the Python language reference. The relevant bit is:

> When an exception occurs in the try suite, a search for an exception handler is started. This search inspects the except clauses in turn until one is found that matches the exception.

Comment: Hmmm...I didn't think "in turn" was explicit enough, but I guess it is. My bad.

Answer (score -4):

Some of the commonly used Exception clause form with try statement

```
**except: Catch all (or all other) exception types.
**except name: Catch a specific exception only.
**except name as value: Catch the listed exception and assign its instance.
**except (name1, name2): Catch any of the listed exceptions.
**except (name1, name2) as value: Catch any listed exception and assign its instance.
**else: Run if no exceptions are raised in the try block.
**finally: Always perform this block on exit.
```

Comment: Nice list but it doesn't answer the question